# Nested if statement does not work

Tags: python

Okay, so I am making a text based adventure and I've introduced the variable gold. I am trying to make it so within one of the story options you have a choice to pick up gold. My syntax looks like this:

```
if choice == "A":
    print("There is no answer. But there is 5 gold on the floor, would you like to pick it up? Type: YES or NO")
yesorno = input()
if yesorno == "YES":
    g = g + 5
    print("You picked them up.",ge,"g")


elif choice == "B":
    print("Someone from a long distance away shouts: 'Shut up",name,"!'. Then the man walks away down what seems like a echoey corridor.")

elif choice == "C":
    print("Nothing happens, you are left to die.")
    sys.exit("You lost")
```

Choosing 'A' works fine, but if I want to choose B or C I have to type them twice as it shows here:

```
Either type A, B or C to choose.
B
B
Someone from a long distance away shouts: 'Shut up g !'. Then the man walks away down     what seems like a echoey corridor.
```

Comment: so whats the error you get and where's the choise B code that gives the error

Comment: You mean choosing B when when the the result "B" is placed in yesorno returns an error?

Comment: If there is an error provide traceback and relevant part of the code (It means [the SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/))

Comment: Neither the line of code you are talking about nor the error is in the question. Please complete your Question!

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Okay, I did what you said. The program runs but I have to type B or C twice, as I put in the question.

Comment: Make sure your indentation is right. It looks like the `yesorno` belongs to choice `A` so it needs the same indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using python 3, I think the problem is with the indentation, and undefined variable `ge`

```
if choice == "A":
    print("There is no answer. But there is 5 gold on the floor, would you like to pick it up? Type: YES or NO")
    yesorno = input()
    if yesorno == "YES":
        g = g + 5
        print("You picked them up.",g,"g")
elif choice == "B":
    print("Someone from a long distance away shouts: 'Shut up",name,"!'. Then the man walks away down what seems like a echoey corridor.")
elif choice == "C":
    print("Nothing happens, you are left to die.")
    sys.exit("You lost")
```

Comment: The variable ge is defined further up, but this sorted it all out, thanks a lot :)